# How to add google map dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Google MAP API v3 with the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function( $ ) 
    {
        var i = 1;

        initMap( $( '.map' ) );

        function initMap( $map )
        {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', function()
            {
                var myOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( -16.920334, 145.770859 ),
                    zoom: 12,
                };
                var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
                var map = new google.maps.Map( $map[0], myOptions );
                drawingManager.setMap( map );
            } );
        }

        $( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.add-map', function()
        {
            i++;
            $( '.maps' ).append( '<div class="map-' + i + '" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>' );
            initMap( $( '.map-' + i ) );
        } );
    } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" class="add-map" value="Add Map">
    <div class="maps">
        <div class="map" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i want to do is when user clicks `Add Map` button, a map will be created dynamically. The default map is loaded but the next map isn't. How can i fix this issue, thank you!

Here is [my fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/duc_doan/uf6LddLt/4/)

Comment: missing "-"  in initMap( $( '.map' + i ) );

Comment: Hint: the window has already loaded when you click the button and will never fire the load event again.

Comment: @ShailendraSharma thank you, I've added  `-` but it can't fix my issue

Comment: @Adam thank you, is there any solution to make it work?

Comment: i have  already fixed this issue,it's working fine

Comment: @ShailendraSharma it only appended new element to `div.maps`, google map is'nt loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/catch_shailendra/4mtyu/1033/)  of your code what is wrong with your code is you open a map on window load by 
        `initMap( $( '.map' ) );` which run `google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', function()`  and later you call same function on click that not make any sense , because this line register window load event to run function inside it's block

and appending new map in existing map also not working, that's all hope This may help

it's not complete code just a idea how this will work